# Gerrit administator role

Tags: gerrit

I would like to know if there is a way to check who is the gerrit administrator for a certain installation.

as a regular user, if I try running the sql query to check list of users, I get an error:fatal: Not a Gerrit administrator

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As member of the Administrators group you can go to People > Groups and then select the Administrators group, which will then show you the members.

If you are not an Administrator, there is AFAIK no way to list them.